# How can I reach cell values when the workbook is not visible in vba

Tags: excel, vba

I need to read/write the values in cells of a workbook, but I cant do this since I change it to visible = false.

`Application.Windows("AutoNodesV2.0.xlsm").Visible = True`

Does anyone know an alternative way to read/write these values of my workbook?

others solutions also will help me, even if i have to use another workbook, I just need my .xlsm hidden and show only my form. Because users will have to keep another excel files open too.

the error occurs when i try to activate the woorkbook on this line:

> **Workbooks("AutoNodesV2.0.xlsm").Worksheets("NodesSheet").Range("D" & 4).Activate**

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Application.Windows("AutoNodesV2.0.xlsm").Visible = True

    Call fillDesigners
    Call fillCheckers

    MainScreen.Show

...
_____________________________________________________________________________________
Public Sub fillCheckers()
    indx = 1

    Workbooks("AutoNodesV2.0.xlsm").Worksheets("NodesSheet").Range("D" & 4).Activate

    Do While Not ActiveCell.Value = ""
        MainScreen.ListBox_CH.AddItem (indx & "." & ActiveCell.Value)
        indx = indx + 1
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe give [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) a read - it's applicable to the use (or non-use) of `Activate` as well.

Comment: ^^ just write the code without using `Select` and `Activate` and you will have no such problems.

Comment: @braX allright i will try it =)

Comment: @BigBen is it possible to define a range with workbook already hidden?

Comment: Assuming you have the workbook variable set already... `Set rng = wb.Worksheets(1).Range("A1")`

Comment: yeaa it worked here! im very grateful guys! I know it was a simple question but in my office no one more knows how to help me, thakns a lot!
@braX

Comment: how can i mark this question as SOLVED? sorry im new on stack overflow